# Ionic fingerprint authentication not working

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am getting an error while using ionic Android fingerprint auth library. The app build without any issue but raise exception when execute

```
androidFingerprintAuth.isAvailable()
```

I tried different devices but the result is the same. The code used is exactly same as in [official tutorial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-fingerprint-auth). I got the same result when i used [Fingerprint AIO](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fingerprint-aio)

Error:

```
LoginPage.html:85 ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at AndroidFingerprintAuth.isAvailable (vendor.js:94758)
    at LoginPage.webpackJsonp.959.LoginPage.fingerLogin (24.js:149)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginPage.html:85)
    at handleEvent (vendor.js:13920)
    at callWithDebugContext (vendor.js:15405)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (vendor.js:14992)
    at dispatchEvent (vendor.js:10369)
    at vendor.js:10983
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (vendor.js:36872)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
View_LoginPage_0 @ LoginPage.html:85
proxyClass @ vendor.js:110244
DebugContext_.logError @ vendor.js:15345
ErrorHandler.handleError @ vendor.js:2076
IonicErrorHandler.handleError @ vendor.js:168788
dispatchEvent @ vendor.js:10373
(anonymous) @ vendor.js:10983
(anonymous) @ vendor.js:36872
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
onInvokeTask @ vendor.js:5285
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
r.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3
p @ polyfills.js:2
v @ polyfills.js:2
LoginPage.html:85 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 32, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

Ionic Info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v6.9.1
    npm               : 3.10.8 
    OS                : Linux 4.15
```

[package.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SnmNOkXJIUR-yewKCcmH1u58t-cJacq0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Make sure you've added the Fingerprint library to your app module, and that you are calling `androidFingerprintAuth.isAvailable()` when the platform is ready in `platform.ready().then(res =>{ androidFingerprintAuth.isAvailable();})`

Comment: I have added it as a provider. The function is called on a button press, so didn't check the platform ready

Comment: Did it work later on?

Comment: It was my mistake. I used ionic 4 tutorial while using ionic 3 for development.

Comment: Oh, I see. That has occurred very often since the release of Ionic 4.